# how to send message with abort in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I've got to abort something if signature is not valid and I also would like to send a message to the view that renders it. I remember being able to do something like this in a previous project of mine, a year ago. But now when I try this

```
    if (!$request->hasValidSignature()) {
        abort(401, 'Signature is not valid.');
    }
```

I get an error that mentions that $message is not available

this is definition of the abort function, so its clear that it takes the message as input.

```
public function abort($code, $message = '', array $headers = [])
{
    if ($code == 404) {
        throw new NotFoundHttpException($message);
    }

    throw new HttpException($code, $message, null, $headers);
}
```

I wonder why do I get this error then:

```
ErrorException (E_ERROR)
Undefined variable: message (View: 
C:\laragon\www\laraone\resources\views\errors\401.blade.php)
```

this is a part of my 401.blade.php that uses that variable...

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="title">401</div>Unauthorized action, {{ $message }}
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `$exception->getMessage()`. From the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/errors#http-exceptions):

> The `HttpException` instance raised by the `abort` function will be passed to the view as an `$exception` variable: `<h2>{{ $exception->getMessage() }}</h2>`

So in your case:

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="title">401</div>Unauthorized action, {{ $exception->getMessage() }}
</div>
```